# Could Christ who carried our sins on the cross forgive those same sins?

Tags: christology, forgiveness, atonement

Christ who bore our sins on the Cross:

> 1 Peter 2:24 (NASB77) 
>   24  and He Himself bore our sins in His body on the cross, that we might die to sin and live to righteousness; for by His wounds you were healed.

Also forgave sins under the Law:

> Luke 5:24 (NASB77) 
>   24  "But in order that you may know that the Son of Man has authority on earth to forgive sins,"-- He said to the paralytic-- "I say to you, rise, and take up your stretcher and go home."

If Christ is the offering for the sins, isn't He forgiving Himself?

Or....

Is it that Christ is the Mediator as high priest to God for the sins under the NT (and God not Christ forgives those sins) but acted as equal to God under the Law but not the sacrafice for those sins?

Answer (score 2):

These passages are dealing with different components of forgiveness. The first text is the basis of all forgiveness of sins, while the second deals with the application of that forgiveness to a specific individual. Remember, forgiveness had been an integral part of Judaism from the beginning.

Comment: You have a very valid point.  What confuses me is Hebrews 10:4.  If  the assumption that Christ's blood was really the basis for forgiveness of all sins under the Law and otherwise, then is it not possoble there is a scriptural conflict and one of the byproducts of that is that Christ is forgiving Himself if He carried those sins to the cross.

Comment: The Old Covenant sacrifices were "types" pointing forward allegorically to the true sacrifice which truly took away sins. Participation under the Old Covenant looked forward in faith by participating according to the commandments. To participate in the ritual without faith is an abomination even under the Old Covenant (Isaiah 1:13).

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be misunderstanding how forgiveness of sin works in God's legal system, so let me also provide a quick explanation with my answer.

> 1 John 4:10 In this is love, not that we loved God, but that he loved us, and sent his Son to be the propitiation for our sins.

Christ was sent to be, and sacrificed as, a propitiation for the sins of His people. A propitiation (also called `atoning sacrifice`) can be thought of as a vessel for sin to be laid upon in order for justice to be exacted upon it (instead of upon the guilty party). We see this type in the Old Testament quite often, where animals (who cannot commit sin) were sacrificed to atone for the sins of man. However, this was not a spiritually sufficient sacrifice, but served merely as a foreshadow of what God Himself would do. Carrying out the sacrifice was how righteous men displayed their trust in God that He would provide that sacrifice for them.

God cannot allow sin to go unpunished, as that would be a lapse in His justice, making Him unjust. Because God *is* just, and cannot do things that are against His nature, His justice must be fulfilled, so the punishment for sin *must* be carried out.

> Romans 6:23 For the wages of sin is death, but the free gift of God is eternal life in Christ Jesus our Lord.

Where "death" means "infinite spiritual separation from God". That means that a finite being receiving that punishment must receive it eternally (for an infinite amount of time), whereas an infinite being (ie, God the Son) is capable of fulfilling that punishment for a non-infinite amount of time. This is what occurs on the cross when Christ exclaims "Why have you forsaken me?" At that very moment, the perfect communion that the Son had had with the Father for all eternity past was ruptured infinitely. The resurrection shows that this communion had been restored, the sacrifice accepted, and forgiveness for sin achieved and granted for all who believe and trust in that finished work alone.

> 1 John 3:5 And you know that he was manifested to take away our sins; and in him is no sin.

So, though Christ carried the sin of His people, He Himself was not guilty of sin, He was a spotless lamb, without blemish (ie, sin). So there was no sin that He needed to be forgiven for. If He had sinned, He wouldn't be God, and wouldn't be infinite, and could not have served as a perfect, infinite atonement for the sins of His people.

Answer (score 0):

As Christians we believe that Christ was the unblemished lamb of God sent to offer himself as a sacrifice for our sins.  For this to occur Christ remained sinless and therefor had no sins to be forgiven.  In the Nicene and Apostles we creed we confess that Christ descended into Hell, and three days later was raised from the dead ascending into heaven without sin.  Because of Christs sacrifice and resurrection we have salvation, but Christ was without sin.